# urbancode deploy post-script

Tags: javascript, urbancode, udeploy

I want to switch (via "switch.variable") application process into 3 different way, based on results returned of component process. Component process contain shell (bash) script which can return strings as follow:

- some text **DIFF** some text
- some text **NO_DIFF** some text
- any text, most likely error message

Then in the same component process I want to process re results of bash script using post-script as follow:

```
if (properties.get("exitCode") != 0) {
    properties.put('Status', 'Failure');
    properties.remove("switch.variable")
    commandOut.println("Error")
} else {
    properties.put('Status', 'Success');
    scanner.register("any text", function (lineNumber, line) {
        if (line.contains("DIFF")) {
            properties.put("switch.variable", "DIFF")
        } else if (line.contains("NO_DIFF")) {
            properties.put("switch.variable", "NO_DIFF")
        }
        commandOut.println(properties.get("switch.variable"));
    });
    scanner.scan();
}
```

Could you help me to write proper post-script?

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a shell script box named 'Shell' in your component process that looks like:

```
echo 'some text: DIFF'
```

For this box you should add a post-processing script like below:

```
if( properties.get("exitCode") != 0 ){
    properties.put('Status', 'Failure');
}
else {
       properties.put('Status', 'Success');
       var regex = "some text";
       scanner.register(regex, function(lineNumber,line){
       var foo = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(':')+1).trim();
       // The ':' is the symbol after which the payload value starts.
       properties.put("Lorem", foo );
});
scanner.scan();
```

Then you put a 'switch' box after your shell script box named 'Shell'.
In the property name of that switch, put `Shell\Lorem`.

From here you can branch your switch cases by drawing arrows with values you want, like DIFF, NO_DIFF, default. 
The default arrow will cover unexpected cases.
Also you may have some another logic for Shell box failure. It will require outgoing arrow with red sign.

Comment: Thank you for answer, in my case how could I check whether result substring contains values like "DIFF" or "NO_DIFF" to switch by them, approach as doesn't work:
var foo = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(':') + 1).trim();
        if (foo.includes("DIFF") && !foo.includes("NO_DIFF")) {
            properties.put("Lorem", foo);
        } else if (foo.includes("NO_DIFF")) {
            properties.put("Lorem", foo);
        }